# Sed replace multiple Patterns in csv files

Tags: perl, unix, csv, sed, awk

I'm trying to replace patterns in csv files that are too large to open with excel,

I'm trying to perform the following,

- Remove all `"` chars
- Replace `(ROI  )` with `(ROI)`
- Replace `(NI  )` with `(NI)`
- Remove all `@` Chars
- Remove all `&` Chars
- Remove all Tab Chars

I have tried

```
sed 's/"//' | sed 's/ROI  /ROI/' | sed 's/NI  /NI/' | sed 's/@//' | sed 's/&//' | sed 's/chr[09]//' file.csv > file.csv2
```

Can this be done?

Ben

Comment: For multiple replacement, you can use `sed -e ... -e .... -e ...`

Comment: For clarification purposes, I used "sed -e 's/"//' -e 's/ROI  /ROI/' -e 's/NI  /NI/' -e 's/@//' -e 's/&//' -e 's/chr[09]//' file.csv > file.csv2"

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/["@&\t]//g;s/(\(ROI\|NI\) )/(\1)/g' file
```